How to translate "measurand" in one word into Russian?
I'm looking for a single word translation of the metrological term "measurand" (the physical quantity intended to be measured) into Russian. "Измеряемая величина" is two words and could also be misleading since it is also a translation for the term "measured value", which has a different meaning.
Is there an established translation of this term to use in scientific and regulatory documentation?

Do note that pushing that "single word, noun-for-noun" approach too far may lead to ridiculous translations like "Возможен капёж воды из кондиционера". Oftentimes we tend to use verbs where English would've used nouns, so if you can't find a commonly used noun -- it's a good sign that a verb might be a better fit. Could you please provide an example sentence to show how you're going to use that noun?


Is there an established translation of this term to use in scientific and regulatory documentation?

There is, but it's измеряемая величина that you didn't like:

311-01-03 измеряемая величина (measurand): Конкретная величина, подлежащая измерению [VIM 2.6]

The above is an excerpt from ГОСТ IEC 60050-300-2015 which is the Russian state standard for translations of electric and electronic metrology terms, so it's as "established" as it gets.
If I were to coin a new single-word translation for "measurand" (that apparently comes from Latin mensurandus), I would use измеряемое, by analogy with other future passive participles like делимое (dividendus), вычитаемое (subtrahendus), означаемое (significandus) etc.
